# Postfix is not logging anything to journal

Tags: 18.04, postfix, systemd-journald

I'm trying to get `journalctl` in Ubuntu 18.04 to log everything, or mostly everything at least.

One thing that I noticed was, that `postfix` does seem to log to journal.
I can clearly see entries when I run `journalctl  -f`. But using the command `journalctl -u postfix`, it only shows when `postfix` was started and stopped.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`?  The postfix logs might be "Not accessible" while you're not using superuser.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, i even tried it as root but no difference.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should try:

```
journalctl -f -u postfix@-.service
```

If this is not working, search for more postfix-services in the `systemctl --all | grep post`